# Why wasn't the flood featured in the Aristocats?

Tags: production-mistakes

*The Aristocats* (1970 Disney animated feature film) was set in Paris, 1910; the same year Paris was heavily damaged by a great flood.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1910_Great_Flood_of_Paris):

> The 1910 Great Flood of Paris (French: Crue de la Seine de 1910) was a catastrophe in which the Seine River, carrying winter rains from its tributaries, flooded the Paris conurbation, France. The Seine water level rose eight metres above the ordinary level.

Why wasn't that featured in the movie?

On the other hand, we have *A Monster in Paris*, which was set in the same year; but it showed the floods very well.

Comment: In addition to not accurately depicting the weather in Paris in 1910, the producers introduced further inaccuracies in showing several cats (not just one, several!) that can talk.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert First of all, that's a kids' show and showing "talking animals" is a very common thing in such works. Second, the talking between animals is just for us to understand their interactions with themselves; but they sound animal when they're interacting with humans (like _The Aristocats_ which cats were "meowing" in front of their owner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the Wikipedia article you linked:

> In March, the Seine finally returned to normal levels.

I don't think there's any precise indication of what month *The Aristocats* takes place in, but judging from the verdant scenery, it clearly takes place in either spring or summer, after the flood had already ended.

[image]

As for why the flood isn't mentioned at all, I expect Disney simply decided they didn't *need* to mention it, as it's not important to the plot.